# Copy files from a list to different locations

Tags: powershell

So, I'm probably going to do this one manually since it's only 44 files. However, it's something I would like to know how to do easier in the future in case if something similar comes up.

Basically, DFS-R was never installed on a replacement file server, and now it's a month later, and I need to get the role installed. Before I do that though, I need to copy the 44 new files that are on what's going to be the secondary replication partner to the primary replication partner so they aren't lost during the initial replication. I did a diff compare using robocopy, so I have the filenames with the full path, and they just need to be copied to the same exact path on the primary server, just with a different server name. So basically:
   "\servername1\share\path1\path2\path3\filename.file" would need to go to "\servername2\share\path1\path2\path3\filename.file"

But since it's 44 items (at least this time, with more or less next time), I'll need a way to cycle through the list, and initiate a copy for each item in the list, just changing the server name.

I'm sure there's a way to do this with Powershell, but I'm not exactly the strongest when it comes to PS, or scripting in general. Any ideas?

Comment: Won't robocopy do this for you?  It was built as a poor man's replication tool.

Comment: Nope. I mean yes, but I would have had to re-do it for probably 2/3's of the files, since most of them were going to different destinations.

Answer (score 2):

"*I can't build this flat pack table and chair. Can you build it for me, so next time I have a flat pack wardrobe, I'll be better at it?*"

See how that totally doesn't work? It won't be easier, you'll be in exactly the same place as you were before. (Wait, you think you'll find a replacement fileserver with missing DFS-R again?? Fix that checklist/procedure first).

The way to make it easier in future is to understand it better; you get that by trying and bashing your head into the problem bit by bit until it makes sense. And this is a perfect problem to work on, because it's about as easy as it gets - single bits of data, one line each, text, process one at a time.

```
Get-Content ListOfFiles.txt | ForEach-Object { 

    Move-Item $_ ($_ -replace 'servername1', 'servername2') -WhatIf

}
```

That stands a chance of working - unless the file paths have quotes `""` inside the text file, that will break. Remove the quotes. Or leave the quotes, but instead pretend it's a CSV with:

```
Import-Csv ListOfFiles.txt -Header Path | ForEach { 

    Move-Item $_.Path ($_.Path -replace 'servername1', 'servername2') 
}
```

Or you can do it in Excel by opening the file and choosing 'text-qualifier: none' in the wizard, then copying the column for destination and search/replace within the column only, then inserting a new column and writing 'move' and using filldown, then select all, copy/paste to notepad, save as a batch file, run.

(but @uSlackr's comment is pretty good - robocopy the replacement file tree over the original, make it sync changed files)